# Laravel API returning results from different route than requested

Tags: php, laravel, apache

After a few days of up-time, my API started to return wrong results. I'm asking the API for `/tours/tour-count`, but it will return the results of `/tours/37` or requesting `/bikes/types/get` will return the same `/tours/37` result. Over time more and more requests seem to be mixed up in a similar fashion.

When I reboot the server, the problems do not appear for a little while (sometimes an hour, sometimes more). There are no errors in any logs (system or Apache). Other websites on our server instance are working fine.

I suspect it has to do with laravel route cache or thread safety.

I would love to supply code, but I have no clue where to start.. Laravel caching is disabled (cache driver set to `none`), when the issue first came up this was set to `file`.

PHP version: `PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)`. Laravel `v8.29.0`

Apache is setup to use HTTP/2, by following these instructions [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache/), where I used `php7.3-fpm`.

On `Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`. When I run `php -i|grep Thread` it returns `Thread Safety => disabled`.

Anything to point me in the right direction, stuck on this for a few days now, no clue where to go from here. Could it be that apache is using the wrong threads and hence returning results from previously requested resources?

Routes:

```
Auth::guard('api')->user(); // instance of the logged user
Auth::guard('api')->check(); // if a user is authenticated
Auth::guard('api')->id(); // the id of the authenticated user

Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

// BIKES
Route::group(['prefix' => 'bikes'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [BikeController::class, 'allInstances']);
    Route::get('/list', [BikeController::class, 'getBikeList']);
    Route::get('/{id}', [BikeController::class, 'get']);
    Route::get('/types/get', [BikeController::class, 'getBikeTypes']);
    Route::get('/{brand}/{model}', [BikeController::class, 'groupedByBrandAndModel']);
    Route::get('/{brand}/{model}/single', [BikeController::class, 'byBrandAndModel']);
    Route::get('/{brand}/{model}/sizes', [BikeController::class, 'getAllSizes']);
    Route::get('/search/{deliveryId}/{collectionId}/{fromDate}/{toDate}', [BikeController::class, 'advancedSearch']);
    Route::get('/search/{deliveryId}/{collectionId}/{fromDate}/{toDate}/{model}', [BikeController::class, 'availableBikesByModel']);
    Route::get('/search/{deliveryId}/{collectionId}/{fromDate}/{toDate}/instance/{bikeInstanceId}', [BikeController::class, 'availableBikesByBikeInstance']);
    Route::get('/search', [BikeController::class, 'advancedSearch']);
    Route::get('/search/{term}', [BikeController::class, 'search']);
});
//Route::get('/test', [BookingController::class, 'test']);

// LOCATIONS
Route::group(['prefix' => 'places'], function () {
    Route::get('/{term}', 'LocationController@places');
    Route::get('/byArea/{area}', 'LocationController@byArea');
    Route::get('/like/{area}', 'LocationController@like');
    Route::get('/get/{area}', 'LocationController@find');
    Route::get('/two/{one}/{two}', [LocationController::class, 'getTwo']);
});

// CUSTOMERS
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer'], function () {
    Route::post('/', [CustomerController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/{id}', 'CustomerController@find');
    Route::put('/{id}', 'CustomerController@update');
    Route::post('/updatePaymentMethod', 'CustomerController@updatePaymentMethod');
});

// BOOKING// CUSTOMERS
Route::group(['prefix' => 'booking'], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'BookingController@create');
    Route::post('/request', 'BookingController@request');
    Route::get('/byBikeBooking/{bikeBookingId}', 'BookingController@byBikeBookingNumber');
    Route::get('/{bookingNumber}', 'BookingController@byBookingNumber');
    Route::put('/{bookingNumber}', 'BookingController@update');
    Route::post('/{bookingNumber}', 'BookingController@get');
    Route::post('/bookingInfo/{email}', 'BookingController@sendBookingInfo');
    Route::post('/{bookingNumber}/verify', 'BookingController@verify');
    Route::post('/{id}/transactions', 'BookingController@createTransaction');
    Route::post('/{id}/transactions/authorize', 'BookingController@authorizeTransaction');
    Route::post('/{id}/transactions/{transactionId}/receipt', 'BookingController@sendReceipt');
    Route::put('/{id}/transactions/{transactionId}', 'BookingController@updateTransaction');
    Route::put('/{id}/transactions/{transactionId}/charge', 'BookingController@chargeTransaction');
    Route::post('/{id}/tickets/message', 'BookingController@createTicketMessage');
});
Route::put('/address', 'BookingController@updateAddress');

// ACCESSORIES
Route::get('/accessories', 'AccessoryController@all');
Route::get('/accessories/{bikeTypeId}', 'AccessoryController@byBikeTypeId');
Route::get('/accessory-categories/{id}', 'AccessoryCategoryController@get');

// ARTICLES
Route::group(['prefix' => 'article'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ArticleController@all');
    Route::get('/overview', 'ArticleController@overview');
    Route::get('/frontPage', 'ArticleController@frontPage');
    Route::get('/category', 'ArticleController@categories');
    Route::get('/routeCount', 'ArticleController@routeCount');
    Route::get('/routeCount/{locationName}', 'ArticleController@routeCount');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'ArticleController@byCategory');
    Route::get('/locations/{locationId}', 'ArticleController@byLocationId');
    Route::get('/locations/by-string/{location}', 'ArticleController@byLocationString');
    Route::get('/tag/{tag}', 'ArticleController@byTag');
    Route::get('/relatedRoutes/{tag}', 'ArticleController@relatedRoutes');
    Route::get('/name/{name}', 'ArticleController@byPostName');
    Route::get('/id/{id}', 'ArticleController@get');
    Route::get('/routeNumber/{routeNumber}', 'ArticleController@getByRouteNumber');
    Route::post('/routeNumber/{routeNumber}/image', 'ArticleController@saveRouteImage');
});

// LocationLinks
Route::get('/location-link', 'LocationLinkController@all');

// Tours
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tours'], function () {
    Route::get('/tour-count', 'TourController@tripCount');
    Route::get('/trips', 'TourController@trips');
    Route::get('/events', 'TourController@events');
    Route::get('/accommodations/{id}', 'AccommodationController@get');
    Route::get('/types', 'TourController@getTypes');
    Route::get('/tags', 'TourController@tags');
    Route::get('/by-name/{name}', 'TourController@getByName');
    Route::get('/by-hash/{hash}', 'TourController@getByhash');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'TourController@get');
    Route::get('/{id}/prices/{tourTypeId}/{peopleCount}/{month}', 'TourController@geTripPrice');
    Route::get('/{id}/prices/{tourType}/{peopleCount}', 'TourController@getPrices');
    Route::get('/{id}/events', 'TourController@tourEvents');
});

// Payments
Route::group(['prefix' => 'payments'], function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', 'PaymentController@get');
    Route::get('/{id}/check_card_payment', 'PaymentController@checkPaymentTransactionStatus');
    Route::put('/{id}/mark_paid', 'PaymentController@mark_paid');
});
```

** Update 22-03-2021 **

We've managed to narrow the problem down to visiting pages that request data from the `routes/by-hash/{hash}` route. It seems to mix up something with the cache. After requesting a tour using the aforementioned url, it caches this result and will return this for all other requests. Currently switching to `Redis` instead of `file`/`memory` caching.

Comment: Please include the routes file.

Comment: @MrEduar Added the routes file

Comment: you should check better if there are any conflicts between  Route::get('/tour-count', 'TourController@tripCount'); and Route::get('/{id}', 'TourController@get'); because it might confuse your id with "tour-count" if you didn't handle this correctly. Try to comment one of these routes and check if it works, if yes you have to rewrite the code in order to make it understanding when using the route with the {id} and when not.

Comment: @Mike It matches routes from top to bottom. The problems started about a month after we added the tours to our api, we were applying the same structure for a year without any problems so far.

Comment: did you try to check somewhere in your request data or in the database about that "37"? is it always that numbers that gets used? or does it change sometimes? in addition it could be nice to post the methods related to the following controllers, in particular:    TourController@get, TourController@tripCount, BikeController@getBikeTypes.

Comment: Something that is coming in my mind now is that you are using both the old syntax to link a route to a controller method 'controllername@method' and the syntax of the last laravel version, I don't know if there might be some compatibility issues when using both, i think no, but you can try to switch all routes to the new syntax if you have time.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the input. However I started refactoring the to new laraval routing syntax after the problems first started. The routes I mentioned where it returns the wrong data were just examples. There are no particular routes which return the wrong data, it's rather all of them once it starts.